# Como utilizar AJAX em um iframe?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, iframe

**Para contextualizar:**

Estou tentando fazer com que somente uma parte da minha pagina HTML seja atualizada, a cada 5seg. Para isso, estou utilizando AJAX. No meio do desenvolvimento, me encontrei com um problema de não conseguir retornar o objeto e a minha view ao mesmo tempo, visto que, ambas eram acessados pela mesma URL ("/`log`").

Então, criei um frame

```
<iframe id="logIframe" src='about:blank' width="900" height="500"></iframe>
```

para que eu mantenha a minha view na pagina (ao redor do frame) e o objeto sendo exibido dentro do frame. **O meu problema** é que, o meu objeto está retornando vazio e eu não sei o porque. Se eu retorno o objeto, ao em vez da view, o objeto retorna corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Do contrario:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Tirei o print retornando um Log, por isso que retorna [obj]. Retornando uma string, simplismente fica em branco).

Meu post que é chamado pela função AJAX:

```
                          // "log"
@RequestMapping(value = "/logTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String iframeLogPost(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
    if (log.getInitLine() == 0 && log.getFinalLine() == 0) {
        try {
            fileNumberLines(log);
            log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
    }

    // View:
    //model.put("path", logsDir);
    //model.put("log", log);
    //model.put("currentPage", "logs");
    //model.put("root", root);

    return log.getContent();
}
```

Minha função AJAX:

```
function reload() {

    var ifrm = document.getElementById('logIframe');
    ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document
            || ifrm.contentDocument;

    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : '/logTest',
        success : function(data) {

            console.log(data);
            ifrm.document.open();
            ifrm.document.write(data); // Escreve no iframe
            ifrm.document.close();
        }
    });
}
```

**Duvida:**
  O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Acho que usar iFrame é meio errado hoje em dia. Por que não faz mesma coisa numa ``div`` na página? De qualquer forma, você precisa transformar o objeto em string antes de escrevê-lo: ``JSON.Stringify(data)``

Comment: Então, eu estava fazendo com uma div antes. O meu problema se inicializou por que eu não conseguia acessar o objeto através do AJAX. Então me falaram que eu devia utilizar a notação @responsebody no meu controller. O problema é que, fazendo desse jeito, eu perdia a minha view, e somente o objeto aparecia na pagina. E se eu não utilizasse a notação, não conseguia acessar o objeto. Então fiquei nessa "cruz", por isso tava tentando de outras maneiras.. Mas acho que vou voltar pra div mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Olá @David Caina, vamos considerar que vc tenha 2arquivos:

Em um vc coloca uma div para receber o iframe, e coloca o ajax com o seguinte código no success:

```
html:
div class=".recept_iframe" /div

no ajax:

setInterval(function(){
    $(".recept_iframe").load("pasta/iframe.php");
}, 5000);//com o setInterval, vai carregar a cada 5segundos
```

- No outro arquivo vc coloca o iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que vc deveria anotar o parâmetro Log com @RequestBody:

```
@ResponseBody
 public String iframeLogPost(@Valid @RequestBody Log log, BindingResult bindingResult,
```

E os campos desta classe deverão ter os nomes e os tipos iguais aos do representado no JSON passado no post ou mapear que campo da classe representa que campo do JSON.